# What is the code quaility standard for method complexity in Java code?

Tags: java, sonarqube

In my project we are using Sonar Qube which has limit for method complexity 10.

If the method complexity is more than 10 then it raises major issues.

Is there a standard which defines the method complexity?

Comment: everybody can set their own sonar-rules/standards. But is it not possible to extract methods from the one(s) you have?

Comment: Is there any standard which says 10 should be the maximum complexity level. Any java standard?

Comment: no. these are not Java standards, these are rules set by sonar, not by Java. You can alter these rules as to your requirements.

Answer (score 7):

The way Sonar Qube determines it's complexity is written down in their [documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Metrics+-+Complexity). The algorithm (if you want to call it) is "Count the number of certain statements".

There are other algorithms to determine the complexity of a particular chunk of code, too. For example, there is the widely known [Cyclomatic Complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity).
However, it doesn't really matter what you use as long as you are (within a project or company) all agree on a metric and a reasonable upper limit.

And always remember that there are times when "the tool" is not right and the code in question is the right choice even if it's complexity is higher than the threshold. This can be for readability reasons or just for plain old performance optimization.

Comment: Probably does not work too well when people start using Java 8 functional style instead of normal loops and conditions.